# Given Unknown Variable Implicated to be Wrapped in Parentheses

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $y = x^2$ 
where $x = -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3$
solve for $y$

Is it implied that when plugging in the values, $x$ is wrapped in parentheses thus making the negative variables positive when exponentiated? Or is it not wrapped, making the variables negative?

I would also appreciate an excerpt on this.

Thank you!

Comment: If $x$ is a real number then $x^2$ is not negative

Comment: $x^2$ is $x$ multiplied by $x$. What is $-3$ multiplied by $-3$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown When a negative number is exponentiated, the exponent goes before the negation of the number, so a $-3^2 = -9$, however, if the negative number is wrapped in parentheses it equates to $(-3)^2 = 9$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is wrapped, so to speak.  If, for instance, $y = x^2$, then if $x = -3$, then $y = (-3)^2 = 9$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you be able to cite me anything? Having that reference would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

All you need to know is the meaning of $x^2$. It is $x$ multiplied by itself. If $x=-5$ for example, then $x^2=(-5)\times(-5)=25$.

When you substitute values into a function, you don't replace the picture of $x$ with the picture of the concrete number. You understand what the function means and then perform the operation on the concrete number. This must be the source of your confusion.

Comment: So you are saying that $x$ is wrapped. Based on that, if $x = -5$ it stands to reason that $x^2 = (-5)^2 = (-5) * (-5) = 25$?

Comment: I like your perceptiveness in seeing the probable cause of OP’s confusion.